# Pass image from first activity to second activity

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Quick question. I'm having an issue passing an image from the first activity to 
the second activity.

In the first activity, I have this code:

```
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            ParseObject todo = urgentTodosAdapter.getItem(position);

           String about = todo.getString("comment");
            String image = todo.getString("image");


            Intent intent = new Intent("com.name.package.DetailsActivity");
            intent.putExtra("about",about);
            intent.putExtra("image",image);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

This code passing the text from the first view perfectly but the image won't work, and I'm not sure what do add. Here's the second activity;

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

    Intent i = getIntent();


    String title = i.getStringExtra("about");
    String thumb = i.getStringExtra("image");



    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleTextView.setText(title);

   ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

   ParseFile imageFile = getParseFile("thumb"); (getParseFile is showing up red, meaning error)
    if (imageFile != null) {
        imageView.setParseFile(imageFile);
        imageView.loadInBackground();
    }

    // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: So the ParseFile is already stored on Parse under the field "image"?

Comment: Correct :) It shows perfectly in a gridview in the previous view but once I try adding it to a detail view, it crashes.

Comment: Is the ParseFile attached to the todo ParseObject?

Comment: String image = todo.getString("image"); ?

Comment: I was thinking ParseFile file = todo.getString("image"); Which is how I came to my answer. What value is stored in the image variable after you call getString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay lets try something like this

First Activity:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


           ParseObject todo = urgentTodosAdapter.getItem(position);

           //get the ParseFile here and then get the url in a string
           ParseFile image = todo.getParseFile("image"); //getParseFile() is a method of ParseObject
           String imageUrl = image.getUrl();

           String about = todo.getString("comment");


            Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.DetailsActivity");
            intent.putExtra("about",about);
            intent.putExtra("image",imageUrl); //pass along imageUrl
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

Second Activity:

```
    private ImageView mImageView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        String title = i.getStringExtra("about");
        String url = i.getStringExtra("image"); //get the url String

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTextView.setText(title);

        //I switched from ParseImageView to regular ImageView here
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        new DownloadImageTask(url).execute();
    }

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String imageUrl;

    public DownloadImageTask(String url) {
        this.imageUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Rich, you rock. The app crashes now :(     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Log: ComponentInfo{com.trendio.adoringbeyonce/com.trendio.adoringbeyonce.DetailsActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
A link in the log is also blue and it points to BitMapFromURL:             connection.connect();

Comment: @HalesEnchanted I knew that would happen just by looking at that code.  You'll need to use an AsyncTask to do the network operations.

Comment: Yep, just fixed it sorry. Change imageview to a member variable as well.

Comment: @RichLuick There's still a few issues in there.  The Parameters should be `AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>`.  Also, I think it would be easier to pass in the url in the `varargs` instead of the constructor, so that it would be `new DownloadImageTask().execute(url);`

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I used Picasso, which was short and simple and it loads perfectly :)

Comment: Good call. I was also gonna recommend Universal Image Loader as well

Comment: @DanielNugent This way works fine with <Void, Void, Bitmap>. But I understand why it would be easier to just ditch the constructor. Thanks for that!

Comment: @RichLuick I just put it into Android Studio like that, and it doesn't even compile.  In order to declare the AsyncTask like that, it has to be `protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {`